# Is thread pausing of any one of two concurrent processes possible?l

Tags: android, multithreading

I am developing phone checking app that will notify user about total mobile usage in a day, its an android app.
One of my biggest confusion is to calculate the usage of any app only when user directly interact with it like notifications of Facebook keeps on coming even user is using any other app,Is it possible that while using any other app like viber,twitter etc Facebook thread can be paused?(so that only relevant app usage count,one process can be handled by other)
If so what are the API and coding interfaces for that?
please help me in this complexity and thanks in advance for ur coordination.

Comment: I think you will need system permissions meaning that the application must be signed or the device must have root rights

Comment: You want to calculate mobile data usage, or time usage?

Comment: i want to calculate time usage of mobile apps

Comment: Just think about what this would man if every app could log what exactly the user is doing and when. This will definitely require root and there won't be any nice high-level APIs around. Interesting idea though.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir can you suggest how to work on roots of device?.

Comment: how to set device root rights?